# Excel debug mode failure

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, mode

I have a system of workbooks for various departments that each have auto_open macros.  I also have a controlling workbook that, on demand, can run its own macro to open each book in the system and collect information.  It normally works great.

However, when debugging the macro in the central workbook becomes necessary, stepping into the command to open any of the supporting books with an auto_open will subvert the debugger and cause the remainder of the code to execute as if the F5 key had been pressed.

I looked for a debug setting to prevent this, as well as any "Open" method parameters that may alter this behavior without luck.  Google searches were fruitless as well.  Is there any way to tell Excel debugger to maintain program control in this situation?  Help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: When I try this out, `Workbooks.Open` method will open a file but the `Auto_Open()` subroutine is not triggered.  In which workbook are you attempting to debug the code?  If it is the "controlling" workbook, simply put a breakpoint *after* the `Workbooks.Open` call, to allow you to resume debugging.

Comment: David, you are correct that when running, the workbook opens and the auto_open is not triggered.  This makes the debug behavior all the more peculiar to me.  A break after the Open statement would solve my issue if I was sure that the error wass confined to the controlling workbook.  I'm worried that some interaction between the two could cause issues and would ideally like to step through the code in both workbooks.

Comment: Right... OK well I have an idea... I will post a brief answer. Not perfect, but I think it will solve your immediate needs.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try this answer out yet??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have observed, the `Workbooks.Open` method does not trigger the `Auto_Open` event, so putting a breakpoint within the 'controlling' workbook, after the new workbook is opened, will not allow you to enter and debug code as you may need to do.

One workaround would be to insert a line of code with a breakpoint that manually calls the `Auto_Open` procedure.  This should allow you to debug code in *each* of the books that are opened:

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\path_to\your_file.xlsm")

Application.Run wb.Name & "!Auto_Open" '// PUT BREAKPOINT HERE!

End Sub
```

**Alternatively**, as suggested [HERE](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/370760-open-workbook-has-auto_open-module.html), port the code from the `Auto_Open` event to the `Workbook_Open` event.

I should have thought of that sooner... I have only ever used `Auto_Open` with XLA/XLAM Add-In files, never with an ordinary workbook file where the `Workbook_Open` event should suffice.